# Copying multiple similar files from several subdirectories

Tags: unix

I have one hundred subdirectories containing 1 file of interest in each of the subdirectories. I want to copy these 100 (*file_of_interest.txt) files of interest to a new folder. How can I do it a shell script?

Comment: do files have same name ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do that something like this:

```
for i in *; do mv $i/files_of_interest.txt ../new_interest_folder; done
```

Note that if the files of interest are sets, such as all the .png files, this ought to work:

```
for i in *; do mv $i/*.png ../new_png_folder; done
```

The * after 'in' could be replaced by any other shell glob. A great way to figure out what's going to happen is to echo things:

```
for i in *folderx *foldery; do echo mv $i/*.png ../new_png_folder; done
```

If this produces the list of commands you would want to run, then go back and remove the 'echo' from the line, and run it again.

The "*folderx *foldery" globs would produce a list of all folders ending in either "folderx" or "foldery"

Answer (score 0):

How about a script

```
#! /bin/bash
find /path/to/root -type -f -name "*.txt" -exec cp {} /target/directory \;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the generous responses. It worked well.